# How to access previous key in a loop in dictionaries without ordered dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate the dict of `month_days` over the keys that is months to perform some calculation to store in another `year_month_cal` dict after each loop.
I'm trying to write a generalized code instead of hard coding the key value each time.

```
month_day = {'JAN': 31, 'FEB': 28, 'MARCH': 31, 'APRIL': 30, 'MAY': 31, 'JUNE': 30, 'JULY': 31, 'AUG': 31,
             'SEPT': 30, 'OCT': 31, 'NOV': 30, 'DEC': 31}
year_cal_no = {}

for k, v in month_day.items():
    month_cal ={}
    if k in month_day.keys():
        V = month_day[k]

        if k in ['JAN']:
            for i in range(1, V + 1):
                cal_no = 40
                month_cal_no = cal_no * i

                print(i, month_cal_no )
                month_cal[k] = cal_no
                year_cal_no[k] = month_cal_no
        if k in ['FEB']:
            for i in range(1, V + 1):
                #Here I want to remove JAN and access the previous key as k-1 or something
                cal_no = month_cal['JAN']
                month_cal_no = cal_no * i
                print(i, month_cal_no)

            month_cal[k] = cal_no
            year_cal_no[k] = month_cal_no

print(year_cal_no)
print(month_cal)
```

Output is:

```
{'JAN': 1240, 'FEB': 1120}
{'JAN': 40, 'FEB': 40}
```

I need help to make this logic more generic rather than hard coding the key each time.

Comment: Use a list instead of a dictionary.

Comment: What's the point of `if k in month_day.keys()`? It has to be in the keys, since you're iterating over the items in the dictionary.

Comment: `V` is the same as `v`, why do you need both variables?

Comment: You're emptying `month_cal` each time through the loop. You should initialize it before the loop.

Comment: Dictionaries don't preserve order before Python 3.7, so "previous key" makes no sense. You _could_ try to maintain a separate list of keys, but that would likely be problematic.

Comment: `if k in ['JAN']:` should just be `if k = 'JAN':`

Comment: @Barmar But if I use a list I won't be able to store the days for the month. I need the key value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of tuples instead of a dictionary. Then when you're iterating over the list you can access the previous index.

Also, you shouldn't reset the `month_cal` dictionary in each iterations, since you lose the information from the previous month.

You should assign `cal_no` before the `for i` loops, since it doesn't change within the loop.

```
month_day = [('JAN', 31), ('FEB', 28), 'MARCH': 31, 'APRIL': 30, ('MAY', 31), 'JUNE': 30, 'JULY': 31, ('AUG', 31),
             'SEPT': 30, ('OCT', 31), ('NOV', 30), ('DEC', 31)]
year_cal_no = {}
month_cal = {}

month, days = month_day[0]
cal_no = 40
for i in range(1, days+1):
    month_cal_no = cal_no * i
    print(i, month_cal_no)
    month_cal[month] = cal_no
    year_cal_no[month] = month_cal_no

for month_index, (month, days) in enumerate(month_day[1:]):
    cal_no = month_cal[month_day[month_index][0]]
    for i in range(1, days+1):
        month_cal_no = cal_no * i
        print(i, month_cal_no)
        month_cal[month] = cal_no
        year_cal_no[month] = month_cal_no

print(year_cal_no)
print(month_cal)
```

Comment: I'm not looking for days of the previous month. I want the year_cal_no[month] value from the previous loop. The Jan cal_no should be used in FEB, so on..

Comment: OK, I fixed that. I get the month name from the previous index of the list, and use that as the key into `month_cal`.

Comment: Thankyou this works. But I have another question, So for the month of June I have another formula to calculate cal_no. How should I incorporate that into this above code?

Comment: you could add `if month == 'JUN':` and do the alternate calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your help.